# Make two inner divs' contents scrollable while respecting outer container boundaries

Tags: html, css

For example given the following HTML structure:

```
<div class=container>
  <div class=segment>
    <div class=header>header</div>
    <div class=content>bla bla...</div>
  </div>
  <div class=segment>
    <div class=header>header</div>
    <div class=content>bla bla...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
.segment {
  height: 50%;
}
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Yet the weird result I'm getting looks like this:

[image]

Also see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrpv0nL/

Why is that and how would I keep the segments contained inside the ... well, container? Just scrollable contents.

Ideally, I want to set the container height to a relative percentage value as well, but if I absolutely have to use absolute values, fine, let's not complicate things too much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues:

1. the .content element needs to have a height added to it, since it shares the space with another element (.header) you need to adjust for that.
2. The parent container (.segment) needs to know how to size itself according to its content + padding etc. `box-sizing: border-box;` does the trick here.

I've updated your fiddle with a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrpv0nL/3/

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies some things. Follow up question: how would I make both segments take up only as much space as its content require? Like if the first segment is almost empty the second segment should take up all the remaining space.

Comment: @user511287 I'm assuming you are wanting the segment to grow/shrink based on it's inner content? You'd have to do that in some other fashion, either by using JS to calculate the content's dimensions, or by using the Flex-Box model. Having the content scrollable makes a solution for this tricky.

Comment: thanks, too bad, I will look into using flexbox here

Answer (score 1):

Hello your problem is that you have hardcoded values, for example the `height` of the container and the `height` of segment, so you force your elements into this.

Here is an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrpv0nL/1/)

P.S.

I was not sure if you wanted to use an overflow, but if you do, you have to add it to `.segment`

Ah okay, so that is what you want?

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrpv0nL/2/)

Comment: No that's not my problem, that's my requirement! I need the container to be height-limited as defined. And I want the *content* to be scrollable, not the segment, which would otherwise scroll the header out of sight.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `overflow:hidden` on your `.segment` and provide your content with a `height`

https://jsfiddle.net/kwjvey8n/

Comment: That seems to work! Actually setting `.segment` to `overflow:hidden; height: calc(50% - 20px);` and `.content` to `height:100%;` seems to do the trick, thanks! I don't understand WHY I have to explicitly set the `overflow:hidden` on `.segment` though, as the height on segment and overflow definition on content already defines sufficient constraints, no?